# How to call a method inside another method in a class in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, methods

How do you properly call a method inside another method in a JavaScript class?

export class XMLLoader{

```
constructor(){



}

// Processes the XML request, i.e retrieves the relevant data etc.
 processXMLReq(xhttp){

    let resultXML = xhttp.responseXML;
    let resultText = xhttp.responseText;


    console.log("The result is: " + resultXML);
    console.log("The result is: " + resultText);

    let x = resultXML.getElementsByTagName("road")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;


    console.log("The first 'road' node value is: " + x);

}

loadXMLDoc(url){

    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
            this.processXMLReq(xhttp);
        }

    };

    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);       // the argument "true" means that the request will be executed in async
    xhttp.send();

}
```

};

As you can see I'm trying to call processXMLReq() inside loadXMLDoc(), why is this not working. Only way I have made it to work is by putting processXMLReq inside the constructor and making it static. This class is supposed to be a utility class for a searchbar class. How can I make it so that I can call processXMLReq inside loadXMLDoc. Because inside my searchbar class I just want to do something like this:

componentDidMount(){

```
  //  let xmlLoader = new XMLLoader();

    let xmlLoader = new XMLLoader();

    xmlLoader.loadXMLDoc('someURL', this.processXMLReq);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Static methods aren't accessed with 'this'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) they are accessed from the constructor or the classname:

```
XMLLoader.processXMLReq(data);
```

or

```
XMLLoader.constructor.processXMLReq(data);
```

Comment: Ah, yes of course! But imagine processXMLReq wasn't static. How would you do it then? Because that is what I actually intended to ask, just forgot to remove the static in front. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If it's not static, then addressing it with this.processXMLReq() should work.

Comment: Actually, looking at your consuming code, are you asking how the consumer references it?

Comment: Yes, because without it being static, and then I get an error that processXMLReq is undefined, although it is an member method.

Comment: In loadXml(), you can reference this.processXML(), but outside of the class instance you cannot. You'd have to do xmlLoader.processXML().

Answer (score 0):

XMLLoader. processXMLreq(xhttp) because it is a static method